# Firestore exclude specific fields from get() of documents in collection

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

How do you get all fields except specific fields of all documents in a collection?

saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411878/python-firestore-query-specific-fields-from-all-documents-in-a-collection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71433141/how-to-get-specific-fields-for-all-documents-from-firestore) but im trying to avoid the overhead of fetching values of fields that may be pretty big (e.g screenshot) when i do not need them, so how do i do that right?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you [execute a query](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/query.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_query.BaseQuery) (or read an entire collection) in Firestore through the Python SDK, you can specify a so-called `projection`, which is documented as:

> `projection`: `(Optional[google.cloud.proto.firestore.v1.            query.StructuredQuery.Projection])`
>
> A projection of document fields to limit the query results to.

I couldn't quickly find a code-sample, but this is the field to specify in your code.

Note for others landing here: the ability to request only specific fields is only available in the server-side/Admin SDKs for Firestore. There is no equivalent in the client-side SDKs.